# undefined method `errors' for #<Comment cannot get errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

So I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `errors' for #<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f1a3e2ecf48>
```

I can get the comment count and other things like that, however, I can't display any errors of the validations.

Here is what I have in terms of my code

`_new_comment`

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= form_with(model: [@product, @product.comments.build], local: true) do |f| %>
      <% if @product.comments.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@product.comments.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @product.comments.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

`comments_controller`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @product, alert: 'Review was not saved successfully.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :rating)
    end
end
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: It can't be `@product.comments.errors`, the errors will be attached to the base object which is `@product` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues

- You can not access `errors` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, but on individual `Comment` objects.
- In your controller action `create`, you do `redirect_to(@product)` on failing to save the comment, which will ignore already built `@comment` object and build a new one (through `form_with(model: [@product, @product.comments.build])`) when rendering the comment form. Instead, you need to only `render` the product page with already built `@comment` object.
- You have `@comment.save` twice in your `create` action.

#### Solution

*products_controller.rb*

```
def show
  # your current logic
  @comment = @product.comments.build
  # render
end
```

*comments_controller.rb*

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render 'products/show', alert: 'Review was not saved successfully.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :rating)
  end
end
```

*_new_comment.html.erb*

```
<%= form_with(model: [@product, @comment], local: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So the comments form is in the products show page https://gyazo.com/a82505a2db70e7cb3d24f8def4434459 it has validations so I'm trying to get the error messages to show, kinda like this https://gyazo.com/e2d72615f23f6a9b56b96a77b389c453

Comment: I have `Review was not saved successfully` showing but I would like an actual message to show.

Comment: What do you see with this solution?

Comment: I see this https://gyazo.com/0e09fb5c0125d2ea394fc851fdafea6c Only the `Review was not saved successfully` shows

Comment: @B.J.B i have updated my answer with much changes in controllers and view both. See if it works now.

Comment: @B.J.B i didn't mention you. My comment is for the downvoter only. :)